# limits.conf nproc not being applied

Tags: linux, limit, sysctl

this is our limits.conf

```
*       soft    nofile  999999
*       hard    nofile  999999
*       soft    noproc  256000
*       hard    noproc  256000
```

and then we check for the changes after a reboot, however max_user_processes is still at 4096. we have fs.file-max at 150000000 in sysctl.conf

```
[root@smpp ~]# su development
[development@smpp ~]$ ulimit -a
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 256772
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 999999
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 4096
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

Comment: Related [Ulimit values in limits.conf vs 20-nproc.conf](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/366548/100397). It's not a duplicate but it highlights that the `noproc` setting may be in two separate places.

Comment: typo.  `s/noproc/nproc/`